# Using Swedish keyboard as English ANSI on macbook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, high-sierra

I have got a macbook pro late 2015 with MacOS High Sierra on it. It has a Swedish keyboard.
How can I use it as an English ANSI type? There are problems with replacement some keys and it doesn't comfortable for my work. MacOS recognizes this keyboard as ISO and it is impossible to change it in system preferences.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the fact that the ISO keyboard puts characters on the key next to the Z that you want on the key to the left of 1, then I think the best thing is make a custom layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) or Karabiner.

(I am assuming you have already set your Input 
Source to US or ABC instead of Swedish, right?)

Comment: Yes, it's the problem. Also I use Ukrainian and Russian layouts and there is a problem with some keys too. Is somewhere a ready solution for my issue?

Comment: This one might work   https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv78ju72b697ais/BritishTilde1.keylayout?dl=0

Comment: It works, thanks. But I can't switch your layout in TextEdit application.